# OCJP - to implement printf in java

Tags: java

```
 public class Demo {


public static void main(String args[])
{   
    double d = 12.345;

    System.out.printf("|%7.3f|\n",d);
}
}
```

**Output is |12.345|**

what does 7.3f indicates.I would also like to know others options that can be used with printf.
If I use

```
   System.out.printf("|%5.3f|\n",d);
```

I get the same output?why?

Comment: http://sharkysoft.com/archive/printf/docs/javadocs/lava/clib/stdio/doc-files/specification.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both specifiers (7.3 and 5.3) say "use 3 digits of precision".  The difference between them is "min width 7" vs "min width 5".  The output of both is a 6 char long string of digits and the decimal point that has 3 digits of precision.

The width specification is useful when the actual width of the data is less-than or equal-to the specified width.  If the data requires more than the specified width to be displayed, then the width is ignored.

[PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)

Answer (score 1):

Follow these links:

- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/Systemoutprintfbncnsnsndn.htm
- http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.lang/System.out.printf.htm
- http://www.particle.kth.se/~lindsey/JavaCourse/Book/Part1/Tech/Chapter05/formatterPrintf.html

Answer (score 0):

The string `"%7.3f"` indicates that you want to format `d` as a floating point number with at most seven characters, and three decimal points.

Comment: seven characters is including decimal pint and fraction.Can u explain

Comment: Right, so the `7` tells the formatter that you want exactly 7 characters of "whitespace" to try to fill with non-blank characters.  The `f` tells the formatter to expect floating point number, and the `3` tells the formatter how many decimal points to attempt to round to.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf("|%2.3f|\n",d);
System.out.printf("|%2.2f|\n",d);
System.out.printf("|%2.1f|\n",d);

System.out.printf("|%6.3f|\n",d);
System.out.printf("|%7.3f|\n",d);
System.out.printf("|%8.3f|\n",d);
```

> |12.345|
>       |12.35|
>       |12.3|
>       |12.345|
>       | 12.345|
>       |  12.345|

Answer (score 0):

The official information source about standard Java classes and methods is the Javadoc:
    [Java SE API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html)

First search for the [System](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) class in the left lower panel.
There (right panel) you find that [out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) is an instance of [PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html).
After clicking that link, you see the Javadoc for [PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) where you find the documentation of [printf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).
These, at least, contains a link to the description for the [Format string syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

*(the Javadoc can also be download from [Java SE Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html))*